# sh: 1: laravel: not found

Tags: ubuntu, installation, laravel-5, laravel-spark

I have registered the spark token and spark has been install on my ubuntu machine,when i run the command

```
spark new application
```

it shows the following error,

```
sh: 1: laravel: not found
Downloading Spark...
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/abrar/testnetic/spark-archive.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 61
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 106
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 108
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 121
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/abrar/testnetic/composer.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/UpdateComposerFile.php on line 56
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/spark could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/abrar/testnetic/config/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/AddCoreProviderToConfiguration.php on line 32
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/abrar/testnetic/config/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/AddCoreProviderToConfiguration.php on line 40
Could not open input file: artisan
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/abrar/testnetic/config/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/AddAppProviderToConfiguration.php on line 32
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/abrar/testnetic/config/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abrar/spark-installer/src/Installation/AddAppProviderToConfiguration.php on line 46

 Would you like to install the NPM dependencies? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

Installing NPM Dependencies...
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! path /home/abrar/testnetic/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/abrar/testnetic/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/abrar/testnetic/npm-debug.log

 Would you like to run Gulp? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

Running Gulp...
[10:53:52] No gulpfile found
```

After cloning the spark-installer from github i run the command

```
composer install
```

and also i have added the spark-installer directory to my system path.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that laravel binary is not available. Check that it is properly installed, and

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

is added to the $PATH. Typing "laravel" in the console should not give an error. If so, refer to the laravel installation manual: https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation

Comment: Path might be ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin depending on the version